# Parse XML SOAP response with Python

Tags: python, xml, soap

I want parse this response from SOAP and extract text between `<LoginResult>` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <soap:Body>
      <LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/wsSalesQuotation/Service1">
        <LoginResult>45eeadF43423KKmP33</LoginResult>
      </LoginResponse>
     </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How I can do it using XML Python Libs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('soap.xml')    

print tree.find('.//{http://tempuri.org/wsSalesQuotation/Service1}LoginResult').text


>>45eeadF43423KKmP33
```

instead of print, do something useful to it.

Comment: SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: I have Python 2.7.3 on MAC osX

Comment: but I use ET.fromstring(...) doesn't work, but parse() works. What's the problem with fromstring

Comment: Might be some encoding issue. Not sure. But try with that modification i made in the example. Add a "." infront of the //. Where you get the string from, straight from http-response?

Comment: Yes it works!, I put "." and It works, and with `fromstring` and `parse` input xml too. thanks

Comment: I'm just curious of why you would parse SOAP in the same way as if you were parsing a common XML document. Because in SOAP you would usually use a framework to build your client based on the WSDL file of the web service, and you would get the fields of the SOAP file "programatically", i.e. using API, and don't have to care doing all the low level parsing...