# Parsing soap/XML response in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, soap, elementtree

I am trying to parse the below xml using the python. I do not understand which type of xml this is as I never worked on this kind of xml.I just got it from a api response form Microsoft.

Now my question is how to parse and get the value of `BinarySecurityToken` in my python code.

I refer this question [Parse XML SOAP response with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828379/parse-xml-soap-response-with-python)

But look like this has also some xmlns to get the text .However in my xml I can't see any nearby xmlns value through I can get the value.

Please let me know how to get the value of a specific filed using python from below xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <S:Header>
    <wsa:Action xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Action" S:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RSTR/Issue</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:To xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="To" S:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="TS">
        <wsu:Created>2017-06-12T10:23:01Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2017-06-12T10:28:01Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </S:Header>
  <S:Body>
    <wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
      <wst:TokenType>urn:passport:compact</wst:TokenType>
      <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:EndpointReference>
          <wsa:Address>https://something.something.something.com</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:EndpointReference>
      </wsp:AppliesTo>
      <wst:Lifetime>
        <wsu:Created>2017-06-12T10:23:01Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2017-06-13T10:23:01Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wst:Lifetime>
      <wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken Id="Compact0">my token</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
      <wst:RequestedAttachedReference>
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
          <wsse:Reference URI="wwwww=">
          </wsse:Reference>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      </wst:RequestedAttachedReference>
      <wst:RequestedUnattachedReference>
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
          <wsse:Reference URI="swsw=">
          </wsse:Reference>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      </wst:RequestedUnattachedReference>
    </wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This declaration is part of the start tag of the root element:

```
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
```

It means that elements with the `wsse` prefix (such as `BinarySecurityToken`) are in the `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd` namespace.

The solution is basically the same as in the answer to the linked question. It's just another namespace:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('soap.xml')    
print tree.find('.//{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}BinarySecurityToken').text
```

Here is another way of doing it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ns = {"wsse": "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"}
tree = ET.parse('soap.xml') 
print tree.find('.//wsse:BinarySecurityToken', ns).text
```

The output in both cases is `my token`.

See https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a namespace dict helped me. Thank you @mzjn for linking that article.

In my SOAP response, I found that I was having to use the full path to the element to extract the text.

For example, I am working with FEDEX API, and one element that I needed to find was TrackDetails. My initial `.find()` looked like `.find('{http://fedex.com/ws/track/v16}TrackDetails')`

I was able to simplify this to the following:

```
ns = {'TrackDetails': 'http://fedex.com/ws/track/v16'}
tree.find('TrackDetails:TrackDetails',ns)
```

You see TrackDetails twice because I named the key TrackDetails in the dict, but you could name this anything you want. Just helped me to remember what I was working on in my project, but the TrackDetails after the `:` is the actual element in the SOAP response that I need.

Hope this helps someone!