# How do I obtain username from web parsing using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x

`TAG: <a href="https://forum.lowyat.net/index.php?s=00e9db5967cb7c48e8b267a9acd49d44&amp;showuser=1061681">MickaelZ</a>`
[Code I use to obtain weblinks, from tag I just want the username.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTlvU.jpg)

```
url = input('Enter - ')
if len(url)<1:url='https://forum.lowyat.net/?showactive#activeusers'
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
    print('TAG:', tag)
```

I want to obtain MickaelZ from TAG as shown on image below:

[results needs filtering to highlighted part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYfcS.jpg)

[code to use to web parse](https://www.py4e.com/code3/urllinks.py)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing soap/XML response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541913/parsing-soap-xml-response-in-python)

Comment: its html parsing

Comment: both are related to each other. Read further here https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-xml-and-html.html

Comment: You can request all headers with the requests import. Then some manipulations, dont think you really need soup for this? Maybe I am wrong. edit : Did not see the link to your code nvm.

Comment: Need help to filter the tags to obtain usernames only

Comment: tag.content[]  #works