# Can not extract SessionId

Tags: python, xml, soap, elementtree

I am trying to extract sessionId from my SOAP API response (XML). However, no matter what I try Python still give me that sessionId is empty (which it is not when I print the response as text).

I have tried what suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828379/parse-xml-soap-response-with-python), however it does not seem to work in this case. Maybe since I can only get the root, but I am not sure how to go from elementroot to elementtree. 
See the response XML and my code below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <LoginResponse xmlns:ns10="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/reportrequest" xmlns:ns9="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/reportresponse" xmlns:ns8="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/matrisrequest"           xmlns:ns7="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/matrisresponse" xmlns:ns6="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/servicerequest" xmlns:ns5="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/serviceresponse"            xmlns:ns4="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/machinerequest" xmlns:ns3="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/machineresponse" xmlns:ns2="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/base"          xmlns="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/security">
            <ns2:session>
                <ns2:sessionId>xxxxxx</ns2:sessionId>
            </ns2:session>
        </LoginResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>




response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers, auth=('xxxx@xxx.com', 'xxxxx'))

root = ET.fromstring(response.content)
sessionId = root.findall('.//{ns10:http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/security}ns2:sessionId')
```

I don't get any error messages, just "[]" when I use this code. Tried other methods as well, but in that case I get "None".

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend using something SOAP-specific - e.g. SUDS Community (it's fork of Suds Jurko which is a fork of original Suds - both abandoned) or Zeep (not related to suds). They make extracting data easier with object-like access and even constructing objects so you don't have to deal with it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, nice to hear. Will consider doing that then. Would have been really glad if someone knows some easy way to read the XML in the way I have formatted the code as well though, so if someone knows please tell me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sessionId` element is bound to the `http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/base` namespace. This works (notice that no prefix is used):

```
sessionId = root.findall('.//{http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/base}sessionId')
```

Since there is only one `sessionId`, you could use `find()` (which returns a single element) instead of `findall()` (which returns a list).

---

Another option is to create a dictionary with prefixes and use those in the search method. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works! I am a little new to this, but I guess the logic is that it was the prefix ns2 that bounded sessionId and the link together then?

Comment: Yes, `xmlns:ns2="http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/base"` in the XML file associates the `ns2` prefix with the `http://caretrack.wirelesscar.net/base` namespace, and `ns2:` in `<ns2:sessionId>` signals that the `sessionId` element belongs to that namespace.

Comment: Did it now @DanielHaley. Sorry.

Comment: @JonasH - No worries. Good question. :-)